# Android sdk - install by hand

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I am trying to install android-studio, and setup android sdk.

Since `dl.google.com` is blocked from my area, I had setup a proxy for sdk manager, but even that it would get timeout when download some big package.

e.g

```
Preparing "Install Android Support Repository (revision: 47.0.0)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
"Install Android Support Repository (revision: 47.0.0)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.0.2)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3952940.zip
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3952940.zip
"Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.0.2)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 26.1.2)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-4077558.zip
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-4077558.zip
```

But I could manually download these files according to links provided above.

Say I already got `android_m2repository_r47.zip` on my disk, and the sdk is located at `/mnt/star/program/android/android-sdk`.

Then what is the target dir to install these the uncompressed file?

**BTW**, I can recall that when eclipse is the default IDE for android the sdk could be downloaded directly. It would be nice if google could provide download for all-in-one sdk packages again, since some place on the earth still blocks google sites.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Extract Folder, (Example : build-tools ) in : SDK Root Directory. or if it doesn't exist with this name, Create a folder with this name ( build-tools ) and then Open SDK manager and now, you can see Added Package in List.

Comment: I have figured out most of the target dir, except for `emulator-linux-4077558.zip`, can you suggest what target dir should be used for emulator?

Comment: Ok, I have solved the issue, it seems that after the proxy get update metadate, then could disable the proxy to install the packages, really weird, but thanks for your help.